# Cisco ASA WebVPN RDP Plugin: how to open automatically a program?

Tags: vpn, cisco, remote-desktop

i'm using Cisco ASA WebVPN RDP Plugin to connect to a RDP server. I need to auto execute a program at startup... with standard RDP i simply add: remoteapplicationcmdline=C:\myprgram.exe

How to do with Cisco ASA WebVPN ? What is a suitable parameter to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put it in all users -> Startup on the server instead. [Here's](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/products_configuration_example09186a00808c0603.shtml#step3) a link to some documentation on the RDP plug-in for 8.X. It lists some parameters and shows you how to configure but a startup app isn't one of them.